# What abilities, mechanics, classes, spells, etc. are changed by Kaedrin's PrC Pack?

Tags: mods, neverwinter-nights-2

I've never messed around with [Kaedrin's Prestige Class Pack](http://nwn2customcontent.wikidot.com) before, but I'm in the process of installing it now because it'll let me put together the build I want for my next OC/MOTB run. (For the curious, I want to use the Stormsinger PrC to have a 30 Warlock for Eldritch Blast purposes and a 14 Bard for song purposes, with some other goodies besides).

It's easy to go through the feat, class, and spell lists and find all the new stuff -  and there's *tons* of it, but I haven't been able to find a good list of existing feats, mechanics, and other things that Kaedrin's changes or replaces rather than simply adds. Some of these are fairly easy to spot over at [NWN2DB](http://nwn2db.com/) once you've been told to look for them. For example, [Expert Tactician](http://nwn2db.com/library/feats/?general#item_1095) was changed from a base version which was bugged and didn't actually do anything, to a flat +1 BAB feat. However, not all changes are even documented to that degree; I've seen references that Kaedrin's nerfs Combat Expertise by making the to hit penalty apply to touch attacks, but I can't find documentation of this anywhere.

Is there a list somewhere of all the *existing* things changed by Kaedrin's, to complement the excellent documentation of all the new things which it adds?

Answer (score 1):

There is an [update log](http://nwn2customcontent.wikidot.com/update-history-and-documentation) on Kaedrin's website (in the menu under 'Update History and Documentation').

To give a taste, as the entire list is way too long to put here:

> *1.42.1 changes*
>       
> Add message to Hawkeye about requiring ranged weapons
>       
> Artist feat text clarified
>       
> Boon of the Unlucky now has a 10% chance not to consume a use of Aura of Unluck and a 5% chance you will regain two uses of Curse.
>       
> Breath of the Dragon description now indicates it can only be used while in dragon shape.
>       
> Briar Web description updated to indicate it deals 3 points of damage.
>       
> Characters with less than 25 druid who have Emberguard gain access to a lesser form.
>       
> Cloud Mind now accounts for Epic Inspiration
>   
> ...